# Using the "grep" function to Create Y axis label for boxplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-science

I created a loop to make 57 boxplots that uses `grep` to pick out the variables I want. However, for whatever reason the Y axis is always labeled the first variable it grabs despite the fact that it grabs all 57 unique variables and creates the loop. I was wondering if someone could take a look at it to see how I could get the Y axis to correspond to what the data actually is. Below is my code.

```
labely = names(ivf_dataset)[grep("_DMR_", names(ivf_dataset), ignore.case = T, fixed = TRUE)] #grabbing first only why?

myboxplot <- function(mydata=ivf_dataset, myexposure, myoutcome  )  { 
  bp <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x = as.factor(get(myexposure)), y = 
        get(myoutcome))) +
        geom_boxplot()                                                  
  print(bp)
}

# test one variable
myboxplot(myexposure = "ART_CURRENT", myoutcome = "H19_DMR_mean") 

# creating loop for 57 boxplots
outcomes = names(ivf_dataset)[grep("_DMR_", names(ivf_dataset), ignore.case = T)] #pulls out dmr names 

allplots <- list()

for (i in seq_along(outcomes)) {
 allplots[[i]]<- myboxplot (myexposure = "ART_CURRENT", myoutcome = 
                         outcomes[i])$plot + xlab("ART_CURRENT") + 
 ylab(labely)  
}

allplots
```

Comment: is the `ivf_dataset` from a package? or something you have locally?

Comment: its just my dataset that I'm grabbing stuff using grep to make my boxplots

Comment: Can you try with `aes_string` and without using `get` in your function (`myboxplot`) - easier in my experience. Also in your `ylab` call you need to specify `labely[i]` - currently it'll always get the first one. Lastly you don't need a `for` loop - using `lapply` would be better I think.

Comment: Gautam, that works thank you! Otherwise, I have tried using the aes_string but I am not sure how that all works. Otherwise I have no idea how lapply works and the for loops seems to be working ok.